# Recommended VB.NET Code Generators

Tags: vb.net, code-generation

Can someone recommend some good VB.net code generation tools?

I only need a tool for developing desktop applications. So the web side of things doesn't really concern me too much.

Comment: You will have to provide some more info, like what exactly you want to generate, and the amount of effort/control you have/want over this process.

Answer (score 5):

[CodeSmith Generator](http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/generator) has a bunch of [Visual Basic Templates](http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/generator#templates).

Answer (score 4):

The de-facto standard for code generation (especially for .NET languages) seems to be [CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com/).  The latest version will cost money, however, they have made an older version [freeware](http://www.codesmithtools.com/freeware.aspx).

If you'd like to go with something free and open-source, [MyGeneration](http://www.mygenerationsoftware.com/portal/default.aspx) is also quite good, and can actally use (after some conversion) CodeSmith templates.

Answer (score 2):

The Microsoft copy of CodeSmith is [T4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_Template_Transformation_Toolkit), built into VS 2005 & 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I only know of a couple of products that are not free:

There is CodeRush from DevExpress:
http://devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/

Miguel Castro has one called CodeBreeze:
http://www.steelbluesolutions.com/Summary/CodeBreeze/Default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

CodeSmith has a ton of templates and supports the latest technologies. It does cost money but it is well worth it in the time you will save as well as the support that comes with it. If you are using Linq to SQL, check out our PLINQO templates. There is currently a sweet CodeSmith offer on plinqo.com

Thanks

-Blake Niemyjski